# Reset Password link redirecting to Login page Admin Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

I am using Magento2 version `2.4.4`

When i am trying to do forgot password from admin, After entering email and captcha,i got reset password link in email, but when i am clicking on that link, it is redirecting to login page.

if anyone have any idea, please let me know.

Comment: Let me know if anyone facing this issue?

Comment: Please confirm , Are you trying that link in other incognito window  ? Also review the magento logs if there is any entry when you were redirected to login page ?